# Wicket: get input from TextField updated by script

Tags: java, wicket

I render a TextField. It's value is populated by script, not the user. I need to get that value from Java but I get `null` by doing `textField.getInput();`

Any ideas how to get that value and use it in Java code?

Comment: It seems to be its right behaviour, from [docs](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html#getInput()): _Gets the request parameter for this component as a string._ With this method you should be able to get textfield content **after** the form has been submitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem a few month ago. One problem is, that setting the input value via javascript doesn't fire the "onChange" event which you could easily use to get the value.

The solution I implemented might not be the easiest one, but it's working:

- put a form with a hidden ajax submit link around your input
- when you fill your input with javascript, use javascript also to do a form submit

html:

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<body>
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('input').value = 'test'; document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">fill
        input</a>

    <form wicket:id="form" id="myForm">
        <input type="text" wicket:id="input" id="input"> 
        <a style="visibility: hidden;" wicket:id="submit">submit</a>
    </form>

    <p> Output:
        <wicket:container wicket:id="output"></wicket:container>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the corresponding java:

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

private String inputValue;

public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);

    final Label output = new Label("output", new PropertyModel<String>(
            this, "inputValue"));
    output.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(output);

    Form form = new Form("form");
    form.add(new AjaxSubmitLink("submit") {
        @Override
        protected void onAfterSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            super.onAfterSubmit(target, form);
            target.add(output);
        }
    });
    add(form);

    form.add(new TextField<String>("input", new PropertyModel<String>(this,
            "inputValue")));
}
}
```

Comment: A very good example indeed. Works great. Thank's a lot, @pingunaut

Comment: Good start, I think it can be simpler though.. See my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

- The `TextField` gets an `AjaxFormSubmitBehaviour` with a custom event.
- This event can be triggered by javascript. I use jQuery, as it is provided by Wicket anyway.

See the code:

```
public class Example extends WebPage
{
    public Example(PageParameters pp)
    {
        super(pp);
        final Model<String> m = new Model<String>("");

        Form<Void> f = new Form<Void> ("form");
        TextField<String> textField = new TextField<String>("textField", m, String.class);

        textField.setOutputMarkupId( true );
        textField.setMarkupId( "myuniqueid" );

        textField.add( new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior("customevent")
        {
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target)
            {
                System.out.println("Model value:"+m.getObject());
                target.add( this.getComponent() );
            }
        } );
        f.add(textField);
        add(f);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="$('#myuniqueid').val('test'); $('#myuniqueid').trigger('customevent');">fill
        input</a>

        <form wicket:id="form">
            <input wicket:id="textField"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of using customevent , i used "onblur" in java code  and thus updated html as <input wicket:id="metaComment" value="" onblur="" 
          style="width: 145px !important" type=text>